# Reproduce the scenario when several JobExecutions exist for a particular JobInstance

Tags: spring-batch

> [Restartability](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#restartability) The launching of a `Job` is considered to be a 'restart'
>   if a `JobExecution` already exists for the particular `JobInstance`.

`Job.isRestartable()` it's `true` by default.

How to reproduce this scenario with several `JobExecutions` for a  particular `JobInstance`?

- When I'm adding `.retry(MyException.class)` on a step level, the new trial doesn't
  add another record to **batch_job_execution**  table.
- When adding `@Schedule` to `jobLauncher.run()` then subsequent executions produce new
  `JobInstances` with corresponding `JobExecutions` (1:1 relation)
- Finally, the `@Retryable` annotation near `jobLauncher.run()` doesn't work, job is running only once with it.

Comment: if subsequent executions produce a new job instance each time, this means you do not have the same set of identifying job parameters passed in. Can you share what job parameters do you pass each time? Do you have a `RunIdIncrementer` set on your job or a date/time parameter passed in?

Comment: Yes, I used different parameters, thank you.